Why are two solutions giving different answers in this problem?
 Here is a quadrilateral ABCD with angle $$\angle A = 150^\circ $$ and $\angle B =90^\circ $ . We are also given that AD=AB=BC and We are asked to find $\angle ADC$ . One method to solve this is here,. Here we do a geometric construction and draw AE parallel to BC and and CE parallel to BA . We can see it forms a square ABCE and an equilateral triangle ADE. and after this we play around with it and find that our answer is $45^\circ$. But we can solve this problem via cosine rule as well and if we go by that approach,. Here if we apply cosine rule in $\triangle ADC$ Like this $$ DC^2 = a^2 + \left( \sqrt{2} a \right)^2 - 2(a)(\sqrt{2}a) \cos(105^\circ) $$ ($\sqrt2 a$ = AC from $\triangle ACB$) and after finding DC, we can apply cosine rule for $\angle ADC$ and we will finally get $$ \angle ADC = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}\right) $$ which is NOT $45^\circ$. So what's going on? Why two correct methods are giving different answers here?. Am I making some mistake? I have checked it already several times so I don't think that there is any mistake in calculation. please tell me where I am going wrong.

$\displaystyle \arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{3})^2}}\right) = \arccos \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 45^{\circ}$

@sudeep5221 OH MAN!. That was a silly mistake:( , should I delete this now or it doesn't matter if it remains here? Also can you think of any other method to solve this? that would be a really great insight
